# Django: How to get list of choices of choice field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have `Choices`:

```
all_choices= Choices(
        ('val1', _("val1 text")),
        ('val1', _("val2 text")),
        ('val3', _("val3 text")),
        ('val4', _("val4 text")),
    )
```

I am looking for function that returns list of all choices like:
`list=['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']`

I could not manage to do it so far
Is there any proper wat to get list of choices?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the options data with:

```
>>> Your_Model.options.field.choices
(('var1', 'val1 text'), ('val2', 'val2 text'))
```

So, from that you can get a list of keys with:

```
>>> [c[0] for c in Your_Model.options.field.choices]
['var1', 'val2']
```

and use `c[1]` if you want the `val text` part.